# Receive nested anonymous objects in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need a ASP.NET MVC controller, which receives anonymous object from JS in JSON to iterate thru its properties. I used to do this, receiving `Dictionary<string, object>`. But now one of values is `Array`, and insted of

`receivedDictionary[Photos] = [object, object, object]`

it gets it as

`receivedDictionary[Photos[0]] = object, receivedDictionary[Photos[1]] = object, receivedDictionary[Photos[2]] = object`

I get not one dictionary entry with key = Photos and value = array, but many entries with key = Photos[x] and value = object.

How do I get it as one entry in dictionary or is there any better way to get it as dynamic anonymous object and iterate thru its properties just like in JS?

UPD: JSON looks like this:

```
{"fields":{"TotalFloors":"9","HouseNumber":"10","Photos":[{"id":0,"ParentID":0,"OriginalUrl":"py4s1y3uyqu","OriginalExt":".jpg","ThumbUrl":"2hn04w2lzuu","FormatUrls":{"WH_109_82_Url":"4cwjarqudvo","WH_766_454_Url":"oofm5qo21rr"}},{"id":0,"ParentID":0,"OriginalUrl":"t3csgq20iro","OriginalExt":".jpg","ThumbUrl":"j1uwwburmse","FormatUrls":{"WH_109_82_Url":"gm4qoery1u2","WH_766_454_Url":"a3c20re3g1d"}}],"Details":"Other details"}}
```

Controller definition:

```
        [HttpPut]
        public ActionResult restId(string className, int id, Dictionary<string, object> fields)
        {
            ....
        }
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like? And the code that creates the JSON? Do you have control over that code?

Comment: Can you post an actual snippet of the JSON?

Comment: Yes, I do have control over client side code.

Comment: Maybe a `dynamic` type would work for you?  An anonymous type still requires compile-time type safety, and if the inputs aren't structurally known then you can't provide that.  Maybe you can describe more about the use case here?

Comment: David, maybe, and how to iterate thru properties of dynamic, using reflection? To say more I can add that this controller is created to edit object of any class of website's model, using reflection. This particular controller is getting inputs and looking into class properties with reflection using input's keys and depending on property's type deciding what to do with input's value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JsonValueProvider` used by the `DefaultModelBinder` seems to be treating array in an odd fashion in this case (based on the source [here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonValueProviderFactory.cs)), so even a `dynamic` will most likely have the issue. (Don't think you'll have this issue in MVC 6 however)

However, calling the `JavascriptSerializer` directly (which funny enough is what the default provider uses) produces the results you're after:

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var res = js.DeserializeObject(@"{'TotalFloors':'9','HouseNumber':'10','Photos':[...],'Details':'Other details'}");
```

To address your issue you could either alter the parameter to a string and run the above code in your action (obviously replacing the JSON string with the parameter), just means the JSON you're submitting from the front end would need to look more like:

```
// wrapping the JSON object in quotes to stringify it
{ 'fields' : "{ 'TotalFloors': '9', 'HouseNumber': .... }" }
```

Otherwise you could implement a custom `JsonValueProvider` like the one proposed here: https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/347099

The custom value provider is probably the cleaner solution.

Comment: How could you possibly know this? I mean that if you call directly, you get needed result. That's the answer I was hoping for. Thanks, I'll pass JSON as a string now and deserialize how you described. Cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks again, man, everything's working fine, I'd never figure it out myself.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Call it a fluke; first thing I tried to was to replicate using the serializer directly, and that returned the desired results. So I did a little more digging into the value provider, and found the code I linked to.